# For any $n$, is there a prime factor of $2^n-1$ which is not a factor of $2^m-1$ for $m < n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Is it guaranteed that there will be some $p$ such that  $p\mid2^n-1$ but $p\nmid 2^m-1$ for any $m<n$?

In other words, does each $2^x-1$ introduce a *new* prime factor?

Comment: These are fairly famous and well studied: p is called a **primitive divisor** of the **Mersenne number** 2^n-1.  Zsigmondy's theorem shows that they nearly always exist, which is very helpful in finite group theory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's true (except for $2^6-1=7\times 9$).

This is known as Bang's theorem, and is a corollary of [Zsigmondy's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem).

You can find a proof [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-07/S0002-9939-97-03981-6/S0002-9939-97-03981-6.pdf) (Theorem 3).

Answer (score 7):

This result is due to Zsigmondy (1892), with special cases $(b=1)$
(re)discovered by Bang (1886), Birkhoff & Vandiver (1904) ... see
Ribenboim, *The New Book of Prime Number Records*, p. 43, 67-68, 338, 437.
Vandiver, a [prolific researcher](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/%7Ehistory/Mathematicians/Vandiver.html) on FLT = Fermat's Last Theorem, applied it to the first case of FLT and related diophantine equations,
e.g. see Ribenboim's book *13 Lectures on Fermat's Last Theorem*, pages 52,*161*,206,234,236.

Such results have many applications: a MathSciNet search on
Anywhere=(Zsigmondy or (Birkhoff and Vandiver))  will find
over 35 related Math Reviews. Schinzel (1974, MR 93k:11107)
extended the theorem to arbitrary algebraic number fields $K$:

> If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic integers in $K,\,$ $(a,b)=1,\,$ and $a/b$ is of degree $d$ and not a root of unity, then there exists  $\,n_0 = n_0(d)\,$ such that
> for all  $n > n_0,\,\  a^n - b^n\, $ has a prime ideal factor $P$  not dividing   $\,a^m - b^m\, $ for all $ m < n$.

Later (1993, same MR) "he generalized this to show that every
algebraic number which is not a root of unity satisfies only a
finite number of independent generalized cyclotomic equations
considered by the reviewer [in Structural properties of
polylogarithms, Chapter 11, see p. 236, Amer. Math. Soc.,
Providence, RI, 1991; see MR 93b:11158]".

There are also [elliptic](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409540) and [polynomial](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4829) generalizations.

Answer (score 2):

No. $2^6-1 = 3^2 \cdot 7$. But we have that $3|2^2-1$ and $7|2^3-1$