# Prove that the set is infinite

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $ a_0 = a> 1$  be an integer, and for $ n \ge 0$ , define $ a_{n + 1} = 2 ^ {a_n}-1$ . Show that the set of prime divisors of the terms of the sequence $ a_n$  is infinite.

This is a problem from 38th Brazilian Mathematics Olympiad.

Comment: I don't know the intended method, but an overkill method would be to use Zsigmondy's Theorem or similar. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/for-any-n-is-there-a-prime-factor-of-2n-1-which-is-not-a-factor-of-2m-1

Comment: Tip: Many primes are found by using $2^n-1$ for different values of n

Comment: If $p \mid a_n$, then $(2^p - 1) \mid a_{n+1}$. What do you know about the primes dividing $2^p-1$?

Comment: (By the way, Daniel's comment gives a very neat proof that there are infinitely many primes)

Answer (score 1):

In base $10$, a repeated decimal of any form can be represented as $\frac{x}{10^n-1}$ where $x$ is the repeated digits and $n$ is how many digits $x$ has. Since any repeated fraction can be represented this way, a repeated sequence of $9$s implied by $10^n-1$ should be divisible by any number which has divisors other than $2$ and $5$ if you put in enough $9$s.

You can apply this same logic to base $2$, see if you get the answer...

Comment: It's indeed true that every odd number divides *some* number of the form $2^n - 1$, but we're not considering all of the numbers of the form $2^n - 1$, we're only considering those that are in the given sequence.

Comment: @Dylan Hm... Maybe the same logic applies to the bigger set, but we'd have to prove it...

Answer (score 0):

Assume to the contrary that the set of primes is finite. Then there must exist a prime $p$ such that $p$ divides infinitely many elements of the sequence. Pick such a prime.

Suppose that $p\mid a_n=2^{a_{n-1}}-1$ with $n>>p$. Let $\ell_1$ be order of $2$ modulo $p$. Thus we must have $\ell_1\mid a_{n-1}=2^{a_{n-2}}-1$. Let $\ell_2$ be the order of $2$ modulo $\ell_1$. Then we also must have $\ell_2\mid a_{n-2}$. Continuing this we must have, $\ell_k\mid a_{n-k}$. Observe that $\ell_i\ne 1$, otherwise we will have $\ell_{i-1}\mid 1$, a contradiction. Thus this process will continue until we have $\ell_i=2$. But we also should have $2=\ell_i\mid a_{n-i}$. But $a_{n-i}$ is odd, contradiction! $\square$